# Line bundles on projective space and disk

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, hodge-theory, line-bundles

I'm having a difficult time solving some exercice. I should prove the following :

> Show that any holomorphic line bundle on a disc $\Delta\subset\mathbb{C}$ is trivial. Deduce that any holomorphic line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is of the form $\mathcal{O}(n)$, for some integer $n$ (Actually the same is true for $\mathbb{P}^m$ as well).

The part about the disk is not too hard using the fact that $H^{(p,q)}(\Delta)=0$ when $p\geq 0,q>0$.

This said, I don't seem to able to solve the second part or even see the link between the two. I have found solutions in books but they all take a different approach of this one and I am quite curious of the link between the disk and the projective line manifests iteself in that regard.

Comment: You can cover $\mathcal P^1$ with two open sets biholomorphic to open discs. So when you restrict a holomorphic line bundle on each open subset, it is trivial. So the line bundle is specified by the transition function on the annulus (to $\mathbb C^*$). In fact it only depends on the homotopy class of the transition function, which is classified by how many times the annulus wrap around the origin.